# Android NDK: using other C++ libraries

Tags: android, c++, eclipse

I am trying to run some existing C++ code in an Android application. I have the NDK set up, and have the source files copied into the `jni` folder in my Eclipse project.

My C++ files have includes and namespace uses that come from elsewhere though, and I'm unsure how to properly import (install?) them into my Android project.

Code in C++ file:

```
#include <gvars3/instances.h>
#include <TooN/SVD.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace CVD;
using namespace std;
using namespace GVars3;
```

All of these libraries are "unresolved inclusion". How can I get these libraries into my project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not different from the usual way. You can do one of the following:

- Pull all the source together and build a single .so
- Build the other libraries as separate .so files, and load them *before* your own .so in your Android project (the order is important)